Why do kernel-core and raspberrypi2-kernel4 packages in Rocky Linux repository "latest" have different kernel versions?
I'm using Rocky Linux on a Raspberry Pi, and I noticed that the kernel-core and raspberrypi2-kernel4 packages have different kernel versions. Here's the output from my system:
# uname -a
Linux rocky9 6.1.31-v8.1.el9.altarch

# dnf list kernel-core raspberrypi2-kernel4
Installed Packages
kernel-core.aarch64           5.14.0-427.16.1.el9_4    @baseos          
raspberrypi2-kernel4.aarch64  6.1.31-v8.1.el9.altarch  @altarch-rockyrpi

# ls -l /boot/initramfs*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 49687153 May 15 09:32 /boot/initramfs-5.14.0-427.16.1.el9_4.aarch64.img
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 26933622 Mar 31 11:40 /boot/initramfs-6.1.31-v8.1.el9.altarch.img

Could someone explain why these packages, supposedly the latest in the repository, have different kernel versions? Why is this difference in versioning for the same distribution's repository?
Can I uninstall/remove kernel-core.aarch64 on rocky?
